How to apply styles with DOM in ReactJS and server-side framework?
I am new at reactjs and i want to manipulate styles directly with DOM or inline-styles. I am using useLayoutEffect to make this run as early as possible.


import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'


const App = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('.my-element').style.background = 'red'
  }, [])

  return <div className="my-element">Hello World!</div>
}

export default App

And the effect is runs like regular styles. But, am I doing the right thing? Or is there a better method for applying style directly with DOM?
And let's say I want to use it on server-side or static-side thing, I always has a slight FOUC (unstyled state) before the real styles is applied, like in NextJS for example.
Wanted to learn how to apply styles with DOM, in server-side, in SSG, and what the best way to do it.

please check out Manipulating the DOM with Refs. React was made so devs can avoid working with DOM directly

In React, prefer inline styles, CSS Modules, or CSS in JS like styled components for dynamic styling over direct DOM manipulation to avoid FOUC in SSR/SSG environments like Next.js
const App = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('red');

  return (
    <div style={{ background: backgroundColor }}>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
};

CSS:
.myElement {
  background: red;
}

JSX:
import styles from './App.module.css';

const App = () => (
  <div className={styles.myElement}>Hello World!</div>
);

JSX:
import styled from 'styled-components';
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background: red;
`;
const App = () => (
  <StyledDiv>Hello World!</StyledDiv>
);

